# PySpark: How do I change the value of a row+column based on the value of other row values

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this...

```
+----------+-----+
|      date|price|
+----------+-----+
|2019-01-01|   25|
|2019-01-02|   22|
|2019-01-03|   20|
|2019-01-04|   -5|
|2019-01-05|   -1|
|2019-01-06|   -2|
|2019-01-07|    5|
|2019-01-08|  -11|
+----------+-----+
```

I want to create a new column based on a logic which needs to look back on other rows - not just the column values of the same row

I was trying some UDF but it takes the corresponding row value of the column. I do not know how to look at other rows...

With example:
I would like to create a new column "newprice" - which will be something like this...

```
+----------+-----+----------+
|      date|price|new price
+----------+-----+----------+
|2019-01-01|   25| 25
|2019-01-02|   22| 22
|2019-01-03|   20| 20
|2019-01-04|   -5| 20
|2019-01-05|   -1| 20
|2019-01-06|   -2| 20
|2019-01-07|    5| 5
|2019-01-08|  -11| 5
+----------+-----+-----------+
```

Essentially every row in the new column value is based on not that corresponding row's values but other row's values...

Logic: If the price is negative then look back on previous days and if that day is positive value - take it or go back one more day until a positive value is available...

```
    dateprice = [('2019-01-01',25),('2019-01-02',22),('2019-01-03',20),('2019-01-04', -5),\
     ('2019-01-05',-1),('2019-01-06',-2),('2019-01-07',5),('2019-01-08', -11)]

   dataDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dateprice, ('date', 'price'))
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First populate the `new price` column with the `price` column, but replace the negative values with `null`s. Then you can use the technique shown on [Fill in null with previously known good value with pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343482/fill-in-null-with-previously-known-good-value-with-pyspark) to get the last non-null value, which in this case will be the last positive value.

For example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, last, when
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

dataDF.withColumn("new_price", when(col("price") >= 0, col("price")))\
    .withColumn(
        "new_price",
        last('new_price', True).over(w)
    )\
    .show()
#+----------+-----+---------+
#|      date|price|new_price|
#+----------+-----+---------+
#|2019-01-01|   25|       25|
#|2019-01-02|   22|       22|
#|2019-01-03|   20|       20|
#|2019-01-04|   -5|       20|
#|2019-01-05|   -1|       20|
#|2019-01-06|   -2|       20|
#|2019-01-07|    5|        5|
#|2019-01-08|  -11|        5|
#+----------+-----+---------+
```

Here I have taken advantage of the fact that [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) returns `null` by default if the condition doesn't match and no `otherwise` is specified.

Comment: BTW: I am reading about window stuff... but looking at this I am also trying to see if I can do something like replacing a row's value with value from 2 days ago - irrespective of negative or positive or null... just copying value from 2 days ago or rather n days ago.

Comment: Hi @pault,
If now I want to do it within a name A or B ? How can I do this?

+----------+---+-----+---------+
|      date| name|price|new_price|
+----------+---+-----+---------+
|2019-01-01|  A|   25|       25|
|2019-01-01|  B|    2|        2|
|2019-01-02|  A|   22|       22|
|2019-01-02|  B|   -1|       22|
|2019-01-03|  A|   20|       20|
|2019-01-03|  B|   10|       10|
|2019-01-04|  A|   -5|       10|
|2019-01-04|  B|    7|        7|
|2019-01-05|  A|   -1|        7|
|2019-01-05|  B|    0|        0|
+----------+---+-----+---------+

Comment: Hi @pault the new table is up in the main question end

Comment: w = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

Comment: @SanDNath if you have a new question, either edit your question or post a new one. Don't post code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one using Spark SQL. Let me explain my solution in 2 parts,

First, when the price is negative, we can fetch the most recent date in which the price was positive otherwise we can populate the price itself, as shown below,

```
spark.sql("""
select *,
case when price < 0 then
max(lag(case when price < 0 then null else date end) over(order by date))
over(order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
else price end as price_or_date 
from dataset
""").show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+-----+-------------+
|      date|price|price_or_date|
+----------+-----+-------------+
|2019-01-01|   25|           25|
|2019-01-02|   22|           22|
|2019-01-03|   20|           20|
|2019-01-04|   -5|   2019-01-03|
|2019-01-05|   -1|   2019-01-03|
|2019-01-06|   -2|   2019-01-03|
|2019-01-07|    5|            5|
|2019-01-08|  -11|   2019-01-07|
+----------+-----+-------------+
```

Second, you can do a `left join` on the same dataset using the `date` and this derived column. So, now the ones with price in the `price_or_date` column would come out as `null`. Finally we can perform a simple `coalesce` on them.

Combining them, we can achieve this final query shown below to generate the desired output,

```
spark.sql("""
select 
   a.date
 , a.price
 , coalesce(b.price, a.price) as new_price
from
(
select *,
case when price < 0 then
max(lag(case when price < 0 then null else date end) over(order by date))
over(order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
else price end as price_or_date 
from dataset
) a
left join dataset b
on a.price_or_date = b.date 
order by a.date""").show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+-----+---------+
|      date|price|new_price|
+----------+-----+---------+
|2019-01-01|   25|       25|
|2019-01-02|   22|       22|
|2019-01-03|   20|       20|
|2019-01-04|   -5|       20|
|2019-01-05|   -1|       20|
|2019-01-06|   -2|       20|
|2019-01-07|    5|        5|
|2019-01-08|  -11|        5|
+----------+-----+---------+
```

Hope this helps.