# Pyspark - add missing values per key?

Tags: pyspark

I have a Pyspark dataframe with some non-unique key `key` and some columns `number` and `value`.

For most `keys`, the `number` column goes from 1 to 12, but for some of them, there are gaps in `numbers` (for ex. we have numbers `[1, 2, 5, 9]`). I would like to add missing rows, so that for every `key` we have all the `numbers` in range 1-12 populated with the last seen value.

So that for table

```
key    number    value
a      1         6
a      2         10
a      5         20
a      9         25
```

I would like to get

```
key    number    value
a      1         6
a      2         10
a      3         10
a      4         10
a      5         20
a      6         20
a      7         20
a      8         20
a      9         25
a      10        25
a      11        25
a      12        25
```

I thought about creating a table of `a` and an array of 1-12, exploding the array and joining with my original table, then separately populating the `value` column with previous value using a window function bounded by current row. However, it seems a bit inelegant and I wonder if there is a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I think that in a pyspark context , what you want is tricky. My understanding is that spark is best for working in a columnar manner, adding, filtering, removing columns etc.

Can I presume that you don't know in advance which keys have gaps in the numbers column ?
You can extract this by using groupBy() and agg() (https://hackingandslacking.com/pyspark-macro-dataframe-methods-join-and-groupby-477a57836ff)  and then filtering to keep only the keys that have < 12 rows.

But that's only the start of the fun....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought about creating a table of a and an array of 1-12, exploding the array and joining with my original table, then separately populating the value column with previous value using a window function bounded by current row. However, it seems a bit inelegant and I wonder if there is a better way to achieve what I want?

I do not think your proposed approach is inelegant - but you can achieve the same using [`range`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.range) instead of [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode).

First create a dataframe with all the numbers in your range. You will also want to cross join this with the distinct `key` column from your DataFrame.

```
all_numbers = spark.range(1, 13).withColumnRenamed("id", "number")
all_numbers = all_numbers.crossJoin(df.select("key").distinct()).cache()
all_numbers.show()
#+------+---+
#|number|key|
#+------+---+
#|     1|  a|
#|     2|  a|
#|     3|  a|
#|     4|  a|
#|     5|  a|
#|     6|  a|
#|     7|  a|
#|     8|  a|
#|     9|  a|
#|    10|  a|
#|    11|  a|
#|    12|  a|
#+------+---+
```

Now you can outer join this to your original DataFrame and [forward fill using the last known good value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343482/fill-in-null-with-previously-known-good-value-with-pyspark). If the number of keys is small enough, you may be able to broadcast

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast, last
from pyspark.sql import Window

df.join(broadcast(all_numbers), on=["number", "key"], how="outer")\
    .withColumn(
        "value", 
        last(
            "value", 
            ignorenulls=True
        ).over(
            Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("number")\
                .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
        )
    )\
    .show()
#+------+---+-----+
#|number|key|value|
#+------+---+-----+
#|     1|  a|    6|
#|     2|  a|   10|
#|     3|  a|   10|
#|     4|  a|   10|
#|     5|  a|   20|
#|     6|  a|   20|
#|     7|  a|   20|
#|     8|  a|   20|
#|     9|  a|   25|
#|    10|  a|   25|
#|    11|  a|   25|
#|    12|  a|   25|
#+------+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this **without join**. I have done multiple tests on this with different gaps and it will always work **as long as number 1 is always provided as input**(as you **need sequence to start** from there), and it will always range **till 12**. I used a **couple window**s to get a column which I could use in the **sequence**, then **made a custom sequence** using expressions, and then **exploded** it to get desired result. If for some reason, you will have inputs that do not have number 1 in there, let me know I will update my solution.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
w=Window().partitionBy("key").orderBy("number")
w2=Window().partitionBy("key").orderBy("number").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)
df.withColumn("number2", F.lag("number").over(w)).withColumn("diff", F.when((F.col("number2").isNotNull()) & ((F.col("number")-F.col("number2")) > 1), (F.col("number")-F.col("number2"))).otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
.withColumn("diff2", F.lead("diff").over(w)).withColumn("diff2", F.when(F.col("diff2").isNull(), F.lit(0)).otherwise(F.col("diff2"))).withColumn("diff2", F.when(F.col("diff2")!=0, F.col("diff2")-1).otherwise(F.col("diff2"))).withColumn("max", F.max("number").over(w2))\
.withColumn("diff2", F.when((F.col("number")==F.col("max")) & (F.col("number")<F.lit(12)), F.lit(12)-F.col("number")).otherwise(F.col("diff2")))\
.withColumn("number2", F.when(F.col("diff2")!=0,F.expr("""sequence(number,number+diff2,1)""")).otherwise(F.expr("""sequence(number,number+diff2,0)""")))\
.drop("diff","diff2","max")\
.withColumn("number2", F.explode("number2")).drop("number")\
.select("key", F.col("number2").alias("number"), "value")\
.show()


+---+------+-----+
|key|number|value|
+---+------+-----+
|  a|     1|    6|
|  a|     2|   10|
|  a|     3|   10|
|  a|     4|   10|
|  a|     5|   20|
|  a|     6|   20|
|  a|     7|   20|
|  a|     8|   20|
|  a|     9|   25|
|  a|    10|   25|
|  a|    11|   25|
|  a|    12|   25|
+---+------+-----+
```