# pyspark replacing null values with some calculation related to last not null values

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

hi my question is somewhat related to This ([Fill in null with previously known good value with pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343482/fill-in-null-with-previously-known-good-value-with-pyspark))
but there is a slight change of requirement in my problem that is:

```
   data:                                        expected output:       
   +------+-----+---------+---------+-----+     +------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
   |  item|store|timestamp|sales_qty|stock|     |  item|store|timestamp|sales_qty|stock|
   +------+-----+---------+---------+-----+     +------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
   |673895|35578| 20180101|        1| null|     |673895|35578| 20180101|        1| null|
   |673895|35578| 20180102|        0|  110|     |673895|35578| 20180102|        0|  110|
   |673895|35578| 20180103|        1| null|     |673895|35578| 20180103|        1|  109|
   |673895|35578| 20180104|        0| null|     |673895|35578| 20180104|        0|  109|
   |673895|35578| 20180105|        0|  109|  => |673895|35578| 20180105|        0|  109|
   |673895|35578| 20180106|        1| null|     |673895|35578| 20180106|        1|  108|
   |673895|35578| 20180107|        0|  108|     |673895|35578| 20180107|        0|  108|
   |673895|35578| 20180108|        0| null|     |673895|35578| 20180108|        0|  108|
   |673895|35578| 20180109|        0| null|     |673895|35578| 20180109|        0|  108|
   |673895|35578| 20180110|        1| null|     |673895|35578| 20180110|        1|  107|
   +------+-----+---------+---------+-----+     +------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
```

my expected output is based on last known not null value and sales_qty, if there is sales_qty then the stock value should be adjusted according to that. 
I have tried the following logic

```
        my_window = Window.partitionBy('item','store').orderBy('timestamp')
        df = df.withColumn("stock", F.when((F.isnull(F.col('stock'))),F.lag(df.stock).over(my_window)-F.col('sales_qty')).otherwise(F.col('stock')))
```

but it only works for one null value, can someone please help me achieve the expected result?

Note: the quantity is NOT always in continuous decrease, so need to consider last not null value to calculate the new one

Comment: could you write the definition of `my_window`?

Comment: just a hint - consider last+ignoreNulls with a proper window definition `df.withColumn("val1",last('val1, ignoreNulls = true).over(w))`

Comment: @mrjoseph i have added it in the question

Comment: @mrjoseph i have tried the F.last function the problem with that is it keeps the last value of the column in the memory and the next calculated value is not picked up so it ends up showing something like 
       110 ,109, 110 again

Comment: by saying 'the quantity is NOT always in continuous decrease' do you mean sales_qty or stock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this. I basically generate two columns first(first non null value=110) and stock2 which is basically incremental sum of stock and then subtract them from each other to get your desired stock.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
w=Window().partitionBy("item","store").orderBy("timestamp")
w2=Window().partitionBy("item","store").orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)
df.withColumn("stock1", F.when(F.col("stock").isNull(), F.lit(0)).otherwise(F.col("stock")))\
.withColumn("stock2", F.sum("sales_qty").over(w)- F.lit(1))\
.withColumn("first", F.first("stock", True).over(w2))\
.withColumn("stock", F.col("first")-F.col("stock2"))\
.drop("stock1","stock2","first")\
.show()

+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|  item|store|timestamp|sales_qty|stock|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|673895|35578| 20180101|        1|  110|
|673895|35578| 20180102|        0|  110|
|673895|35578| 20180103|        1|  109|
|673895|35578| 20180104|        0|  109|
|673895|35578| 20180105|        0|  109|
|673895|35578| 20180106|        1|  108|
|673895|35578| 20180107|        0|  108|
|673895|35578| 20180108|        0|  108|
|673895|35578| 20180109|        0|  108|
|673895|35578| 20180110|        1|  107|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
```

If you would like to force your first value to null instead of 110(as shown in your desired output) you could use this.(basically uses rownumber to replace that first 110 value with null) :

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
w=Window().partitionBy("item","store").orderBy("timestamp")
w2=Window().partitionBy("item","store").orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)
df.withColumn("stock1", F.when(F.col("stock").isNull(), F.lit(0)).otherwise(F.col("stock")))\
.withColumn("stock2", F.sum("sales_qty").over(w)- F.lit(1))\
.withColumn("first", F.first("stock", True).over(w2))\
.withColumn("stock", F.col("first")-F.col("stock2"))\
.withColumn("num", F.row_number().over(w))\
.withColumn("stock", F.when(F.col("num")==1, F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col("stock")))\
.drop("stock1","stock2","first","num")\
.show()


+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|  item|store|timestamp|sales_qty|stock|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|673895|35578| 20180101|        1| null|
|673895|35578| 20180102|        0|  110|
|673895|35578| 20180103|        1|  109|
|673895|35578| 20180104|        0|  109|
|673895|35578| 20180105|        0|  109|
|673895|35578| 20180106|        1|  108|
|673895|35578| 20180107|        0|  108|
|673895|35578| 20180108|        0|  108|
|673895|35578| 20180109|        0|  108|
|673895|35578| 20180110|        1|  107|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
```

Additional data **INPUT and OUTPUT:**

```
#input1
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|  item|store|timestamp|sales_qty|stock|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|673895|35578| 20180101|        1| null|
|673895|35578| 20180102|        0|  110|
|673895|35578| 20180103|        1| null|
|673895|35578| 20180104|        3| null|
|673895|35578| 20180105|        0|  109|
|673895|35578| 20180106|        1| null|
|673895|35578| 20180107|        0|  108|
|673895|35578| 20180108|        4| null|
|673895|35578| 20180109|        0| null|
|673895|35578| 20180110|        1| null|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+

#output1
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|  item|store|timestamp|sales_qty|stock|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|673895|35578| 20180101|        1| null|
|673895|35578| 20180102|        0|  110|
|673895|35578| 20180103|        1|  109|
|673895|35578| 20180104|        3|  106|
|673895|35578| 20180105|        0|  106|
|673895|35578| 20180106|        1|  105|
|673895|35578| 20180107|        0|  105|
|673895|35578| 20180108|        4|  101|
|673895|35578| 20180109|        0|  101|
|673895|35578| 20180110|        1|  100|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+


#input2
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|  item|store|timestamp|sales_qty|stock|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|673895|35578| 20180101|        1| null|
|673895|35578| 20180102|        0|  110|
|673895|35578| 20180103|        1| null|
|673895|35578| 20180104|        7| null|
|673895|35578| 20180105|        0|  102|
|673895|35578| 20180106|        0| null|
|673895|35578| 20180107|        4|   98|
|673895|35578| 20180108|        0| null|
|673895|35578| 20180109|        0| null|
|673895|35578| 20180110|        1| null|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+

#output2
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|  item|store|timestamp|sales_qty|stock|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|673895|35578| 20180101|        1| null|
|673895|35578| 20180102|        0|  110|
|673895|35578| 20180103|        1|  109|
|673895|35578| 20180104|        7|  102|
|673895|35578| 20180105|        0|  102|
|673895|35578| 20180106|        0|  102|
|673895|35578| 20180107|        4|   98|
|673895|35578| 20180108|        0|   98|
|673895|35578| 20180109|        0|   98|
|673895|35578| 20180110|        1|   97|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
```

**IF**, the `stock` **quantities are NOT continuous** like this:

```
  df.show()

+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|  item|store|timestamp|sales_qty|stock|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|673895|35578| 20180101|        1| null|
|673895|35578| 20180102|        0|  110|
|673895|35578| 20180103|        1| null|
|673895|35578| 20180104|        7| null|
|673895|35578| 20180105|        0|  112|
|673895|35578| 20180106|        2| null|
|673895|35578| 20180107|        0|  107|
|673895|35578| 20180108|        0| null|
|673895|35578| 20180109|        0| null|
|673895|35578| 20180110|        1| null|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
```

**You could use this**:(i basically compute a dynamic window for each non-null last)

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


w=Window().partitionBy("item","store").orderBy("timestamp")
w3=Window().partitionBy("item","store","stock5").orderBy("timestamp")
df.withColumn("stock1", F.when(F.col("stock").isNull(), F.lit(0)).otherwise(F.col("stock")))\
.withColumn("stock4", F.when(F.col("stock1")!=0, F.rank().over(w)).otherwise(F.col("stock1")))\
.withColumn("stock5", F.sum("stock4").over(w))\
.withColumn("stock6", F.sum("stock1").over(w3))\
.withColumn("sum", F.sum(F.when(F.col("stock1")!=F.col("stock6"),F.col("sales_qty")).otherwise(F.lit(0))).over(w3))\
.withColumn("stock2", F.when(F.col("sales_qty")!=0, F.col("stock6")-F.col("sum")).otherwise(F.col("stock")))\
.withColumn("stock", F.when((F.col("stock2").isNull())&(F.col("sales_qty")==0),F.col("stock6")-F.col("sum")).otherwise(F.col("stock2")))\
.drop("stock1","stock4","stock5","stock6","sum","stock2")\
.show()

+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|  item|store|timestamp|sales_qty|stock|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
|673895|35578| 20180101|        1|    0|
|673895|35578| 20180102|        0|  110|
|673895|35578| 20180103|        1|  109|
|673895|35578| 20180104|        7|  102|
|673895|35578| 20180105|        0|  112|
|673895|35578| 20180106|        2|  110|
|673895|35578| 20180107|        0|  107|
|673895|35578| 20180108|        0|  107|
|673895|35578| 20180109|        0|  107|
|673895|35578| 20180110|        1|  106|
+------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: @Muhammad murtaza thank you for the answer,  but sorry that i forgot to mention that i cant consider that the quantity is always in continuous decrease thats why i cant use this approach, i have to use the latest last nul quantity calculate the next one i have edited the question to add this limitation

Comment: @WasifTanveer i think my code is dynamic like that, any increase or decrease, it will work.. could u perhaps provide additional data rows to show me what you are saying. id appreciate it

Comment: or if you could comment on the additional data test that i have provided in my updated answer.

Comment: @Muhammad Murtaza Thank you for so clear clarification i tested this on my code the code with dynamic windows and random stock values work perfectly well on it. Thank you once again for your time and input, really appreciate it :)