# Carrying over values from most recent row satisfying a condition

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like (a massively larger version of) the following:

```
+---+---+----+----+
| id|  t|type| val|
+---+---+----+----+
|100|  1|   1|  10|
|100|  2|   0|NULL|
|100|  5|   1|  20|
|100|  8|   0|NULL|
|100| 12|   0|NULL|
|100| 20|   0|NULL|
|100| 22|   1|  30|
|200|  5|   1|  40|
|200| 11|   0|NULL|
|200| 19|   1|  50|
|200| 24|   0|NULL|
|200| 25|   0|NULL|
+---+---+----+----+
```

I want to make a new column which, for rows with type `1`, uses `val`, and for type `0`, uses `val` from the most recent entry of type `1`.

The output would look like this:

```
+---+---+----+----+----+
| id|  t|type| val|val2|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|100|  1|   1|  10|  10|
|100|  2|   0|NULL|  10|
|100|  5|   1|  20|  20|
|100|  8|   0|NULL|  20|
|100| 12|   0|NULL|  20|
|100| 20|   0|NULL|  20|
|100| 22|   1|  30|  30|
|200|  5|   1|  40|  40|
|200| 11|   0|NULL|  40|
|200| 19|   1|  50|  50|
|200| 24|   0|NULL|  50|
|200| 25|   0|NULL|  50|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

It's fairly straightforward how this could be done by iteration if we were in a pandas dataframe, but I can't figure out a way to do using tools from pyspark. What I'd like to do is

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

w = Window.partitionBy(['id']).orderBy('t')
df.withColumn('val2',
  sf.when(col('type'), col('val')).otherwise(sf.lag(col('val')).over(w))
)
```

but this yields

```
+---+---+----+----+----+
| id|  t|type| val|val2|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|100|  1|   1|  10|  10|
|100|  2|   0|NULL|  10|
|100|  5|   1|  20|  20|
|100|  8|   0|NULL|  20|
|100| 12|   0|NULL|NULL|
|100| 20|   0|NULL|NULL|
|100| 22|   1|  30|  30|
|200|  5|   1|  40|  40|
|200| 11|   0|NULL|  40|
|200| 19|   1|  50|  50|
|200| 24|   0|NULL|  50|
|200| 25|   0|NULL|NULL|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

I understand why this doesn't work, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I think I could use a `groupby('id').applyInPandas(...)` with a function that iterates through the rows, but this would be really slow, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I feel like you could first fill null values with the last value ([SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343482/fill-in-null-with-previously-known-good-value-with-pyspark)) then implement your `val2` col with multiple `when` statements ([link](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the last function with ignorenulls=True:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

w = Window.partitionBy(['id']).orderBy('t')
df.withColumn('val2',
sf.when(col('type'), 
col('val')).otherwise(sf.last(col('val'),ignorenulls=True).over(w)))
```