# How to replace null values with previous non null values

Tags: pyspark, etl

I have a column that is something like this

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Value1 | Some Value |
| null | Some Value |
| null | Some Value |
| Value2 | Some Value |
| Value3 | Some Value |
| null | Some Value |
| null | Some Value |

and i want

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Value1 | Some Value |
| Value1 | Some Value |
| Value1 | Some Value |
| Value2 | Some Value |
| Value3 | Some Value |
| Value3 | Some Value |
| Value3 | Some Value |

i have used tjava_row but have encountered certain error. i have used the code given below, or should i go for python(ffill) or pyspark for designing the elt job:

```
if (row2.A==null) {
 row2.A = row1.A
} else {
 row2.A=row2.A;
```

Comment: I think the answer to your question can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343482/fill-in-null-with-previously-known-good-value-with-pyspark

Comment: You can do this using java, python, excel, or whatever you want. Please only ask question about programing issues. Currently your question is opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Talend, you can use a tMap with intern variables to use previous values.
You'll need three variables (from the central tab in your tMap) :

- current : `row1.yourValue` `// cache your input data for current line`
- previous : `Relational.ISNULL(Var.current)?Var.previous:Var.current` `//if current line is null, keep the previous one. Otherwise replace 'previous' with current line.`
- getPreviousIfNull : `Relational.ISNULL(row1.yourValue)?Var.previous:Var.current`

  `//if your input data is null : get the previous one. Otherwise get the current` one.

row1.yourValue is your input data.

Then you extract Var.getPreviousIfNull to your output.

[image]

Comment: @Corentin-Thank you for your reply. For current value i am using Var.var1(row1.A), Previous: Relational.ISNULL(Var.var2)?Var.var1:Var.var2  and for getPreviousIfNull Relational.ISNULL(Var.var3)?Var.var2:Var.var3. Please correct me where i am wrong, As i am only getting the Value1 in the entire column.

Comment: i've added a screenshot