# How to forward fill in some columns in PySpark dataframe without using partitionBy?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like the following,

```
+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|           column1  |     column2     |       column3      |
+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|                  1 |             null|                null|
|                null|   A             |                  99|
|                null|             null|                null|
|                null|             null|                null|
|                null|   B             |                 100|
|                null|             null|                null|
|                null|             null|                null|
|                null|   C             |                 101|
|                null|             null|                null|
|                null|             null|                null|
+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

The following is what I expect,

```
+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|           column1  |     column2     |       column3      |
+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|                1   |             null|                null|
|                1   |         A       |                  99|
|                1   |         A       |                  99|
|                1   |         A       |                  99|
|                1   |         B       |                 100|
|                1   |         B       |                 100|
|                1   |         B       |                 100|
|                1   |         C       |                 101|
|                1   |         C       |                 101|
|                1   |         C       |                 101|
+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

I am new to PySpark and I am not sure how I can achieve this using PySpark functions.

Comment: do you have an ordering column? spark does not retain dataframe order due to its distributed nature.

Comment: I actually found the solution. I will update with answer later. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Window functions for this.

1. import functions and create test data.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc, last

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
data = [(1, None, None),
        (None, "A", 99),
        (None, None, None),
        (None, None, None),
        (None, "B", 100),
        (None, None, None),
        (None, None, None),
        (None, "C", 101),
        (None, None, None),
        (None, None, None)]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
```

2. create a Window, in this example i do not specify a column for `partitionBy`, which will lead to the whole df to be loaded (not the best idea in production, I hope you have a suitable column to group by). In `rowsBetween` I specify, that all data between the current row and the first row are looked at.

```py
window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(desc("col1")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
```

3. the `last` function takes the last value it sees, with nulls beeing ignored.

```py
df = (
    df.withColumn("col1", last("col1", ignorenulls=True).over(window))
    .withColumn("col2", last("col2", True).over(window))
    .withColumn("col3", last("col3", True).over(window))
    )

df.show()
```

Which will result in:

```
+----+----+----+                                                                
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|null|null|
|   1|   A|  99|
|   1|   A|  99|
|   1|   A|  99|
|   1|   B| 100|
|   1|   B| 100|
|   1|   B| 100|
|   1|   C| 101|
|   1|   C| 101|
|   1|   C| 101|
+----+----+----+
```

Reference:
[Fill in null with previously known good value with pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343482/fill-in-null-with-previously-known-good-value-with-pyspark)
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.last.html
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.rowsBetween.html